# Concatenar arquivos .html em um .htm com PowerShell

Tags: batch, powershell

Então, eu preciso concatenar milhares de arquivos .html para somente um .htm, já há um arquivo .batch que faz isso pra mim, utilizando o seguinte código:

```bsh
#type *.html > output.htm

@echo off

for /r %%i in (*.html) do (

    if not %%~nxi == output.htm (

        echo %%~nxi >> output.htm
        type "%%i" >> output.htm
        echo. >> output.htm
    )
)
```

O que acontece é que esse processo é extremamente lento, descobri que com PowerShell é mais rápido e tentei criar o código, mas sei pouquíssimo de linguagens, ficou assim:

```
get-content *.html | Set-Content output.htm
```

Beeeeem simples! Até deu meio certo, o problema é que alguns caracteres ficam "corrompidos", como no texto abaixo:

```
O ICMS de responsabilidade das empresas industriais fabricantes de calÃ§ados 
que usufruam do crÃ©dito presumido previsto no inciso XXIX do artigo 57 do 
RICMS/SE, Ã© diferido no recebimento do exterior ou, relativamente Ã  
diferenÃ§a de alÃ­quotas, pelas aquisiÃ§Ãµes em outra unidade federada de 
mÃ¡quinas, equipamentos, ferramental, moldes, modelos, instrumentos e 
aparelhos industriais e de controle de qualidade, e seus sobressalentes.
```

Eu tentei deixar o código assim:

```
get-content *.html | Set-Content output.htm -Encoding UTC8
```

e tentei mudar o código pra outros e tbm não funcionou.

Alguém consegue dar um help?

Answer (score -1):

Possivelmente pode ocorrer de haver multiplicidades de encoding no conteúdo dos seus arquivos html, sugiro testar usando **`-Raw`** e substituir -**`Encoding UTC8`** por **`String`**:

---

```powershell
Get-Content -Raw *.html | Set-Content output.htm -Encoding String
```

---

> ou ainda usando alias

---

```powershell
cat -Raw *.html | sc output.htm -Encoding String
```

---